# Make cron inherit XDG_RUNTIME_DIR

Tags: cron, xdg

I have a cron job that runs `emacsclient` which requires that `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` to be set. I can set the variable to something like `/run/user/1000` in the `crontab` but then this assumes that the owner of the cron is the first user to login (otherwise their `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` would be `/run/user/1001` for example).

Is there a better way to have `cron` inherit the value of `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` from the owner of the cron jobs?

Comment: does your cron job run as user with uid `1000`? Otherwise, this sounds like a bad idea. Do you *really* need to run `emacsclient`, even if that user is not logged into an X session? I ask because there's very likely an easier solution (I don't have one better than actually running a login shell, which runs a script, which runs your emacsclient). I mean, emacsclient makes no sense if there's not already an `emacs` running that it can communicate with, so there's very many reasons this sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/61778 please see this. This could be done on a per-user basis, based on who runs the crontab

Comment: Thanks @Alex, this question is almost a duplicate to the one you link and the solution works as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting to:

#### write dedicated cron script:

Include current user's environment context and additional environment variables.

```
cat << EOF > $HOME/croned_script.sh
#!/bin/bash
source $HOME/.bash_profile
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
#
# your program and arguments from here:
emacsclient
EOF
```

#### append dedicated cron script to crontab list:

In this example the cron pattern runs once at 12:00 noon each day

```
contab -l| sed "-i * 11 * * * bash -c $HOME/croned_script.sh"| crontab
```

Comment: It's worth to note that setting the variable doesn't automatically create a mount for the user directory in "/run/user". The directory "/run/user/1000" is created by systemd. CRON doesn't create it.